# Limit occurrences for rename in Visual Code editor

Tags: visual-studio-code

In Visual Code Editor (v1.44) I'm selecting some text and then expanding the selection with cursors using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd> in order to perform a rename operation.  However, I'd only like to rename a portion of the matched symbols (let's say lines 15-18, below):

[image]

I know I can use <kbd>ALT</kbd> to unselect certain cursors but if the matches are extensive I'd rather just limited the matches in the first place.  Since starting this post I realized I could use a regular expression match (e.g. `"RA.*Elgb"`) which is a decent workaround but I'm still curious: is there a way to limit matches to a region (either a selection or just the next 3 lines or some other)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have at least 2 options, probably more:

1. Select `RA_CA_Mbr_Elgb` and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to add the next match to the selection.  The matches do not need to be contiguous.
2. Or use the new `Selection/Column Selection Mode` - obviously the matches need to be similarly formatted and contiguous, as is your example, for this to work.

[image: column selection mode]

Comment: Awesome, `CTRL-D` is new for me, just what I was hoping for.  Thanks!